# Jstl for each loop items attribute use another variable not working

Tags: jstl, el

getResults is list

**case 1 :**

```
 <c:forEach items="${getResults} var="s1">
      ${s1}
 </c:forEach>
```

**case 2 :**

```
 <c:set var="res" value="getResults" />
 <c:forEach items="${res} var="s2">
      ${s2}
 </c:forEach>
```

In above code case (1) is printing list of results fine

but in case (2) just res is printing

Iam trying to print results using case 2 please help me out

that is need for my project

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:set var="res" value="getResults" />
```

This sets the res variable to the string "getResults". If you want it to be a reference to the same object as the getResults attribute, you want

```
<c:set var="res" value="${getResults}" />
```

This is completely unnecessary though, since you can iterate directly on `${getResults}`