# jstl for each loop items attribute assigns string directly

Tags: jstl, el

getResults is list

**case 1 :**

```
<c:forEach items="${get_Results} var="s1">
  ${s1}
</c:forEach>
```

**case 2 :**

```
<c:set var="res" value="${fn:replace("get Results",' ','_')}" />
<c:forEach items="${res} var="s2">
  ${s2}
</c:forEach>
```

In above code case (1) is printing list of results fine

but in case (2) just res is printing

Iam trying to print results using case 2 please help me out

that is need for my project

Comment: You asked basically the same question yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998497/jstl-for-each-loop-items-attribute-use-another-variable-not-working). the value of res is a string. Iterating over a string makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with the obvious, working case 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is how to use a dynamic variable (with a name evaluated at runtime) in JSTL.

The solution is to use `requestScope`, as this:

```
<c:set var="varname" value="get Results" />
<c:set var="dynamicvarname" value="${fn:replace(varname,' ','_')}" />
<c:forEach items="${requestScope[dynamicvarname]} var="s2">
  ${s2}
</c:forEach>
```

`requestScope` is a JSP [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043), which is a map of request-scoped variable names to their values.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this `<c:set var="res" value="${fn:replace("get Results",' ','_')}" />`  u are getting just a string, `<fn:replace()>` take three arguments and u give them, first  - where replace - it is a string "get Results", second what symbol to replace - it is ' ' (empty space), and finally which symbol will - "_". And as a result of method `<c:set>` you are getting string - "get_Results".

If you want to make replace of each object on list `${get_Results}`, than you have to do next:

```
<c:forEach items="${get_Results} var="s1">
  <c:set var="s1_replaced" value="${fn:replace(${s1},' ','_')}" />
  <c:out value="${s1_replaced}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Code above will loop each object in your list and on every object will make operation replace " " (space) on "_" and print it.